# Paypal for online shop with multiple merchants

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I am integrating Paypal to my online shop which has multiple merchants selling goods. Anytime a merchant enters a good into the system, the system will ask for his Paypal email to receive the payment from buyers.
I am now getting stuck at integrating Paypal with my shop:

1. Which API can I use to let buyers to send payment directly to merchant Paypal account (don't need to send via my application)?
2. Does merchant need to make any configuration within his Paypal account (such as enable API access or something similar)? This will be a huge problem for me when my merchants don't have good IT skills. They don't know what does API mean.

Please kindly suggest me the API from Paypal which I should use. I am using PHP if it is needed info.

Kind regards

Comment: Refer https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/. There is sample php code given for each api. There is no cakphp plugin for paypal. You have to write in php.

Comment: In fact there is a PayPal component for CakePHP. I wrote about it in my answer.

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

All PayPal requires is you build a form with the right parameters: `amount`, `business`, `currency`, `item_name` etc.

If merchants have some form of profile on your website, then you could store their PayPal address in it and use that value as the `business` parameter (where payments are sent to) when someone checks out on “their” store on your website.

Hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CakePHP PayPal component to integrate your site with PayPal:
https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal.

But to use PayPal API anywhere, a PayPal account has to be a Pro account. You have also to get an API username, password and signature for each account (from PayPal -> Profile -> API Settings -> Signature) and put it in your code.

A sample code in your controller may look like this:

```
class SomeController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Paypal');

    public function payWithPaypal() {
        $this->Paypal->config['password'] = 'your paypal password';
        $this->Paypal->config['email'] = 'your paypal email';
        $this->Paypal->config['signature'] = 'your paypal signature';
        $this->Paypal->sandboxMode = false;

        $this->Paypal->amount = 100;
        $this->Paypal->itemName = 'some item';
        $this->Paypal->quantity = 1;
        $this->Paypal->localeCode = 'GB';
        $this->Paypal->currencyCode = 'EUR';
        $this->Paypal->returnUrl = 'some url';
        $this->Paypal->cancelUrl = 'some url';
        $paypal_url = $this->Paypal->expressCheckout();
        $this->redirect($paypal_url);
    }
}
```

Read the component documentation and code comments inside the component class to get familiar with the details.